# I have multiple threads but they are not working together

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying print these `Log.w("aa",String.valueOf(x));` , `Log.w("bb",String.valueOf(x));` by multi threads but It's should working together but It's not.

*Logcat result*

```
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 0
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 1
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 2
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: etc... to 999
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 0
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 1
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 2
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: etc... to 999
```

*But should be mixed doesn't wait first thread when end like this*

```
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 0
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 0
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 1
2019-08-30 11:28:28.885 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 1
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 2
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 2
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/aa: 3
2019-08-30 11:28:28.909 4554-4554/com.test.app W/bb: 3
etc...
```

*Code*

```
    Thread a = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Thread", "Running");
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for(int x = 0 ; x < 1000 ; x++){
                            Log.w("aa",String.valueOf(x));
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread b = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Thread", "Running");
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for(int x = 0 ; x < 1000 ; x++){
                            Log.w("bb",String.valueOf(x));
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    a.start();
    b.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs in the MainThread, because of `runOnUiThread`.

You need to remove `runOnUiThread`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++){
                    Log.w("aa",String.valueOf(x));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++){
            Log.w("bb",String.valueOf(x));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

}

But if you want to do background work in Android you should use AsyncTask or rxJava.

Comment: you basically create two new threads but asked them both to print on the UI thread.... thus pretty much defeating the purpose of having a new thread. Also your expected result will not necessarily occur... it can be random when it comes to threads

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need runOnUiThread.? both thred calling the main thread. if you are not doing anything releated to UI changes you can do it without runOnUiThread. without runOnUiThread both threads can works simeltaniously.